# Parameterizations of Lines.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Which of the following equations give alternate parameterizations of the line L parameterized by: **r(t)=(1+2t)i +(2+2t)j -(1+4t)k?**

a. -(1+t)i-t*j+(3+2t)k

b, (3-2t)i+(2-2t)j+(3-4t)k

c. (2+3t)i+(1+3t)j+(1-6t)k

We are working on the paramaterization of lines. We need to find which one of the the three choices is equal to the given equation. I set the components equal to each other to see if they satisfy the equations, and found the answer to be A, but i'm unsure if that is what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your given vector like this to make the role of $t$ obvious:
$$r(t)=(i+2j-k)+(2i+2j-4k)t$$
So your line $L$ goes through the point $i+2j-k$ and is parallel (or antiparallel) to the vector $2i+2j-4k$.

Just look at each of your possible answers and check these conditions. The easiest way to check the parallel condition is to split the possible answer in the same way I split $r(t)$ and see if the second part (multiplied by $t$) is a multiple of $2i+2j-4k$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.